# MySQL Query is so slow it's take over 500 sec, any other suggestions

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, query-optimization

```
SELECT `mi`.`Item_Description` AS `Item_Description`,
       `psi`.`Item_ID` AS `Item_ID`,
       `mt`.`Type_Description` AS `Type_Description`,
       `psi`.`Item_Type_Id` AS `Item_Type_Id`,
       `psi`.`Item_Unit` AS `Item_Unit`,
       (Select Sum(Item_Quantity_Delivered) From project_store_input Where Item_ID = psi.Item_Id) AS `Total_Input`,
       (Select Sum(Output_Quantity) From project_store_output Where Item_Id = psi.Item_Id) as Total_Output,
       ((Select Sum(Item_Quantity_Delivered) From project_store_input Where Item_ID = psi.Item_Id) - (Select Sum(Output_Quantity) From project_store_output Where Item_Id = psi.Item_Id)) as Balance

FROM (`project_store_input` `psi`
     LEFT JOIN `materials_items` `mi` on(`mi`.`Item_ID` = `psi`.`Item_ID`)
     LEFT JOIN `materials_types` `mt` on(`mt`.`Type_ID` = `psi`.`Item_Type_Id`)
     LEFT JOIN `suppliers` `s` on(`s`.`Supplier_ID` = `psi`.`Supplier_ID`)
     LEFT JOIN `project_store_output` as `pso` on (pso.Item_Id = psi.Item_ID))
GROUP BY `psi`.`Item_ID`
```

This SQL query is to calculate the balance from two tables "project_store_input" and "project_store_output" the result should browse (Item Name, Item ID, Total_Input, Total_Output, Balance)

Any suggestions please,
thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the GROUP BY for?

Comment: make sure that you have created the index in each fields that you want to select

Comment: Also, you're not selecting or filtering on either pso or supplier in any way, so why include them at all?

Comment: Why are you using subquerys to do the sum if it is on the same table of the select? Don't need it, just put the sum and group by the other fields that is not on the sum.

Comment: Also, extending Jorge's point, correlated subqueries tend to be S-L-O-W

Comment: Please post an EXPLAIN.

Comment: thanks guys I think the main problem was in the indexing !!!

Comment: @uvais you are right, I have to check the indexing

Comment: ok , good luck , carry on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write sub-queries. You can directly add quantities.

Try this:

```
SELECT mi.Item_Description AS Item_Description,
       psi.Item_ID AS Item_ID,
       mt.Type_Description AS Type_Description,
       psi.Item_Type_Id AS Item_Type_Id,
       psi.Item_Unit AS Item_Unit,
       psi1.DeliveredQty AS Total_Input,
       pso1.OutputQty AS Total_Output,
       (IFNULL(psi1.DeliveredQty, 0) - IFNULL(pso1.OutputQty, 0)) AS Balance
FROM project_store_input psi
LEFT JOIN materials_items mi ON mi.Item_ID = psi.Item_ID
LEFT JOIN materials_types mt ON mt.Type_ID = psi.Item_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN suppliers s ON s.Supplier_ID = psi.Supplier_ID
LEFT JOIN project_store_output AS pso ON pso.Item_Id = psi.Item_ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Item_ID, SUM(Item_Quantity_Delivered) DeliveredQty FROM project_store_input GROUP BY Item_ID) psi1 ON psi.Item_ID = psi.Item_Id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Item_Id, SUM(Output_Quantity) OutputQty FROM project_store_output GROUP BY Item_Id) pso1 ON psi.Item_Id = pso1.Item_Id
GROUP BY BY psi.Item_ID
```

**OR**

```
SELECT mi.Item_Description AS Item_Description,
       psi.Item_ID AS Item_ID,
       mt.Type_Description AS Type_Description,
       psi.Item_Type_Id AS Item_Type_Id,
       psi.Item_Unit AS Item_Unit,
       SUM(Item_Quantity_Delivered) AS Total_Input,
       SUM(Output_Quantity) AS Total_Output,
       (SUM(Item_Quantity_Delivered) - SUM(Output_Quantity)) AS Balance
FROM project_store_input psi
LEFT JOIN materials_items mi ON mi.Item_ID = psi.Item_ID
LEFT JOIN materials_types mt ON mt.Type_ID = psi.Item_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN suppliers s ON s.Supplier_ID = psi.Supplier_ID
LEFT JOIN project_store_output AS pso ON pso.Item_Id = psi.Item_ID
GROUP BY BY psi.Item_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. You are doing unnecessary subquerys.

```
SELECT `mi`.`Item_Description` AS `Item_Description`,
       `psi`.`Item_ID` AS `Item_ID`,
       `mt`.`Type_Description` AS `Type_Description`,
       `psi`.`Item_Type_Id` AS `Item_Type_Id`,
       `psi`.`Item_Unit` AS `Item_Unit`,
       Sum(Item_Quantity_Delivered) AS `Total_Input`,
       Sum(Output_Quantity) as Total_Output,
       (Sum(Item_Quantity_Delivered) - Sum(Output_Quantity)) as Balance
FROM `project_store_input` `psi`
     LEFT JOIN `materials_items` `mi` on(`mi`.`Item_ID` = `psi`.`Item_ID`)
     LEFT JOIN `materials_types` `mt` on(`mt`.`Type_ID` = `psi`.`Item_Type_Id`)
     LEFT JOIN `suppliers` `s` on(`s`.`Supplier_ID` = `psi`.`Supplier_ID`)
     LEFT JOIN `project_store_output` as `pso` on (pso.Item_Id = psi.Item_ID)
GROUP BY `mi`.`Item_Description`,
         `psi`.`Item_ID`,
         `mt`.`Type_Description`,
         `psi`.`Item_Type_Id`,
         `psi`.`Item_Unit`
```

Comment: in this way I can't get the total for each item

Comment: Then group just by `psi`.`Item_ID`